# Python: Add list to existing tuple (containing lists)

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have an existing tuple containing two list:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [4, 5, 6]

tuple = list_a, list_b
tuple = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

How do I add another list to this tuple without creating a tuple in the tuple containing the first two lists?

```
list_c = [7, 8, 9]

#Code to add list_c to tuple

tuple = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable... why can't you use a list?

Comment: Also, don't name your tuple *tuple*, as it shadows the built-in *tuple*.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Only where reassignments are concerned. You can still add two together.

Comment: @Coldspeed I thought adding two tuples together creates a new tuple. It doesn't seem to modify the original. `>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> id(a)
140559292145464
>>> a += (3, 4)
>>> id(a)
140559292436248`

Comment: No, I was just trying to say that their immutability is irrelevant here. :)

Comment: @Coldspeed It is the definition of relevant here. "How do I add another list to this tuple..."

Comment: I don't think OP is concerned as to whether the original is modified or not... hard to say without more clarification... OP seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @JasonStein for future reference, it is better if you mark duplicates using the *Flag* option on the question and selecting Mark as Duplicate. This will automatically post a comment on your behalf linking to the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your 3rd list inside a singleton tuple and then add it to the existing one:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [4, 5, 6]

tuple1 = list_a, list_b    
tuple1 += ([7, 8, 9],)

print(tuple1)
```

Output:

```
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

Also, I'd advise against using `tuple` as a variable name, especially when working with tuples...

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it is a bad idea to use tuple as a variable name.

Secondly, tuples are immutable, i.e you cannot change an existing tuple. So what you can do is, create a new tuple and assign the existing value.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [4, 5, 6]

tuple1 = list_a, list_b

list_c = [7, 8, 9]
tuple2 = tuple1 + (list_c,)
```

thus, `tuple2` is the final tuple that you need. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`tuple = tuple + (list_c,)`

Is there a particular reason you are using a tuple of lists, rather than a list of lists? Tuples are immutable and reassigning / remaking at every step is much more expensive than `list.append()`.